# "What's an engineer's favorite music to listen to?"

Tags: anagram

The answer is within the following scrambled letters, but there is also a letter missing:

**R-O-M-T-A-H-H-?**

I've been at this for hours and I cannot come up with anything whatsoever. I strongly believe the scrambled letters equate to two words, not one.

Comment: Just positing a guess: I see the word "math" in there, so it could be a pun off of "Mathcore", a subgenre of metal, but I can't see how to translate "-hor" to "core" with an engineering pun.

Comment: The riddle is very vague, so I am not sure if the answer would be an artist or genre of music; but I believe it would be genre.

Comment: Assuming missing letter as 'Y', it turns out to be - "O! A Rhythm"

Comment: Hmm, using the text "Ah mother" (E added), Google shows "Gentleman" by Psy. The answer can go into many directions...

Comment: Given that RHO is in the letters, I wonder if the missing letter is from the Greek alphabet, which is pretty popular with engineers.

Comment: I think it's probably some bad pun like "Moh chart" (Mozart) although I don't have a good explanation for Moh in this example.

Answer (score 5):

Partial (non)-answer:

> E gives "MATH HERO"
>  N gives "MATH HORN"
>  S gives "OM THRASH"
>  U gives "MATH HOUR"
>  W gives "OHM WRATH"

I don't know that any of those looks enough like a music genre to be right.
Though if it were a engineering *guru*, "S" would be fitting....

Answer (score 2):

If "within the scrambled letters" doesn't mean "uses all the scrambled letters", but rather "uses only the scrambled letters" (plus the missing letter mentioned), then it could be:

> A motor

with the missing letter being

> O

and dropping

> the 2 Hs

The explanation would be

> that it's a joke, based on the idea that engineers are so into engineering that they would rather listen to the sweet sound of a finely-tuned motor running well than anything that might more conventionally be called music, to the point where they would consider such a motor to be music.

(Note that I'm not claiming that that's my view of engineers!)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, what about:

> Oh Martha! (A added)

This is a song by some bands, examples:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGTMho80m0E
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAKUCLaqkUc

Link to engineers:

> It seems harsh, but I guess most 'male' engineers want more women in their work environment, so...

Answer (score 1):

I've got a half-assed theory.

Perhaps it is [not]...

> CHROMATH

Due to widespread usage of a related word, including our two topics of interest...

> [CHROMATIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_(disambiguation))